# How to get Checked rows values of a ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` in WPF application with a `CheckBox`.

I want to save the values of all Checked rows in a WPF List ...

How can I achieve this?

**My ListView**

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewChapter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" Height="100" Margin="22,234,17,28" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Label Name="lblChapterID" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding ChapterID}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <CheckBox Name="chkChapterTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding ChapterTittle}" Checked="chkChapterTitle_Checked" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can bind the `IsChecked` property directly to `IsSelected` of the ListViewItem.  Use `RelativeSource` to bind to the element.

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Path=IsSelected}"
```

Now if you use `SelectionMode=Multiple` for the ListView, you can pull the checked items directly using `SelectedItems`.

```
var chapters = new List<Chapter>();
foreach (var item in listViewChapter.SelectedItems)
    users.Add((Chapter)item);
```

Comment: i have Added IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Path=IsSelected}" in ListView..

Now How i can Get Checked rows values ..

Comment: After Adding this in CheckBox
Only Single CheckBox checked, I want multilple checkBox Checked....

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [MVVM pattern](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html) for your WPF application, and [if you're going to use MVVM then you'll want an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx).

Then, it would be a case of creating a type that represents your databound object (e.g `Book`), then having a collection of this type on your view model (e.g. `ObservableCollection<Book> Books`).

You would then bind a `Selected` boolean property for example on your `Book` type to the CheckBox's `IsChecked` property in your ListBox ItemTemplate.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
```

You may not want to polute your domain object (`Book`) with properties purely used for the UI (`Selected`), so you could create a `BookViewModel` type which augments the `Book` type and reshapes the object purely for the purposes of the view.