# Wpf CheckedListbox - how to get selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've made a CheckedListbox in xaml using this code:

```
                    <ListBox Height="340" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And its bind to this collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<String>> Sections { get; set; }
private CheckedListItem<String> _selectedSection;
public CheckedListItem<String> SelectedSection
    {
        get { return _selectedSection; }
        set 
        {
            _selectedSection = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSection"); 
        }
    }
```

The CheckedListItem class looks like this:

```
    public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private T item;

    public CheckedListItem()
    { }

    public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }


    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set a breakpoint in the _selectedSection = value; part of the code but it never gets triggered when i select/deselect an item in the CheckedListBox.

My question is how can I get the selected item every time its selected/deselected ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your `XAML` to

```
<ListBox Height="340" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item}" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You are probably clicking on the actual `textblock` control inside the `checkbox` or the `square` control which doesn't trigger `selectionchanged` for a `listbox`. If you try to click outside the bounds of the rectangle say the `whitespace` then it will fire.

It'll be more work if you just want the `checkbox` as the datatemplate since you want to select/deselect `listboxitem`' based on the `checkbox` **IsChecked** property. So just wrap it inside a `ListBoxItem` and you should be good to go.

Comment: That solution only works if you click on "special" places on the item/checkbox

Comment: But when i click the checkbox nothing happens. I've to click left to checkbox to get it to select an item and "firing" the bindin.

Comment: I tested the solution, I click on checkbox/text/space it selects the item.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the setter of the SelectedSection property, does that fire when you select an item in the list ? For some reason my breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Comment: Yup, I tested the solution before posting the answer.

Answer (score 8):

My solution (based on **Suplanus** and **lll** solutions above):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Checkboxes}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Label}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I set ListBoxItem IsSelected property througt style (because standard **lll's** way not work well)! In this case, when CheckBox is checked ListBoxItem is selected and vice versa. SelectionMode in this case also works well. You can add SelectedItem (or similar property) in Single SelectionMode

```
<!-- xaml -->
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCheckbox}" SelectionMode="Single"
// cs
public CheckboxData SelectedCheckbox { get; set; }
```

or maybe even better, work directly with ItemsSource (Checkboxes collection in this case) in behind code (your ViewModel for example).

**Behind code** (for example):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class CheckboxData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            Checkboxes.Add(new CheckboxData { Id = i, Label = $"Checkbox {i}" });
    }

    public IList<CheckboxData> Checkboxes { get; set; } = new List<CheckboxData>();
}
```

**Note:**
If you want change Checkboxes collection (or selected item) from behind code (and reflect changes in UI) you have to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** and notify when collection (or selected item) has been changed (literally, when object has been re created).

Answer (score 2):

I think the better solution is to not declare in a ListboxItem, because the selection on Hover is shown on the Checkbox.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" /> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution to work:

```
<ListBox Height="340" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Item}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: Technically, what you have with the RelativeSource is what I have in the DataTemplate. I just made it explicit so that you can understand in case you're not familiar with DataBinding.

Comment: My solution doesn't work that well either. When i get the sections from my database and want to set IsChecked = true on some of the items then its state is correct in the viewmodel but its not reflected in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was binding to a Dictionary<string, MyEnum> and none of the solutions above worked.  Taking a cue from [a question about ListView with checked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986543/how-to-get-checked-rows-values-of-a-listview-in-wpf), I was able to come up with the following that seems to act like one would hope - including being able to get the selected items from lstMyEnumTypes.SelectedItems.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstMyEnumTypes" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyEnumsDict}"
  SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
        Content="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```