# How to access checkbox in ListBox items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I'm trying to make a ListBox with checkboxes into it.

In xaml I have:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lstMaterialesCL}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="lstMaterial" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Name="chkMaterial" Content="{Binding DescCompuesta}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

and my ListBox looks as:

[image]

It is ok, but look it, when I checked "Municipales" the item in the ListBox is not selected, and when I select in the ListBox "Industriales" it is not checked

If I inspect the items selected into the ListBox it don't coincide with the items Checked

```
 foreach (var item in lstMaterial.SelectedItems)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(((MaterialesCL)item).DescCompuesta);
 }
```

It shows me "Oficiales", "Industriales" and "Destrucciones" but the user was want select "Municipales" and "Destrucciones"
How I can to make coincide the ListBox items selected with the CheckBox checked if the CheckBox checked is mandatory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193242/wpf-checkedlistbox-how-to-get-selected-item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193242/wpf-checkedlistbox-how-to-get-selected-item

Comment: Check these post. Hope you will get anwser.

Comment: thnks so much @AyyappanSubramanian I testing you suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I tested all your suggestions, thank you so much to all, after all tests, the solution how I need it is more or less like this:

On xaml:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MaterialesVM}" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
 Name="ListBoxMateriales" Width="300" Height="200" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
         <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
             </Style>
         </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 Content="{Binding DescCompuesta}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
     <Button Name="btnPrueba" Style="{StaticResource BotonContent}" 
 Content="Selected" Width="80" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="btnPrueba_Click"/>
     <Button Name="btnLimpia" Style="{StaticResource BotonRechazar}" 
 Width="30" Height="30" Click="btnLimpia_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Margin="5,0,0,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Limpia Todos"/>
     <Button Name="btnMarca" Style="{StaticResource BotonAceptar}" 
 Width="30" Height="30" Click="btnMarca_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Margin="5,0,0,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Selecciona Todos"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

On this way I don't care on where clicked, the item will be selected or un-selected (on the CheckBox and on the ListItem)

And to see the items selected:

```
 // To show the selected items
 private void btnPrueba_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var selectedItems = MaterialesVM.Where(x => x.IsChecked);
     foreach (var item in selectedItems)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(((MaterialesCL)item).DescCompuesta);
     }
 }
```

To select all items:

```
 // To select all items
 private void btnMarca_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var Items = ListBoxMateriales.Items;
     foreach (MaterialesCL item in Items)
     {
         item.IsChecked = true;
     }
 }
```

To un-select all items:

```
 // To un-select all items
 private void btnLimpia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var Items = ListBoxMateriales.Items;
     foreach (MaterialesCL item in Items)
     {
         item.IsChecked = false;
     }
 }
```

and my classes are:

MaterialesCL.cs

```
public class MaterialesCL : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Material { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string DescCompuesta { get; set; }
    private bool _ischecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _ischecked; }
        set 
        { 
            _ischecked = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); 
        }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

LstMaterialesCL.cs

```
public class LstMaterialesCL : ObservableCollection<MaterialesCL>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LstMaterialesCL()
    {
        BasculaEntities _context = new BasculaEntities();
        var Query = (from m in _context.Materiales
                         select new { m.Material, m.Descripcion}
                        ).OrderBy(m => m.Material).ToList();

        foreach (var item in Query)
        {
            this.Add(new MaterialesCL { Material = item.Material, 
                Descripcion = item.Descripcion, DescCompuesta = item.Material.ToString("000") + " - " + item.Descripcion,
            IsChecked=false});
        }
    }
}
```

and on my UserControl MaterialesVM is an instance of LstMaterialesCL

```
 LstMaterialesCL MaterialesVM = new LstMaterialesCL();
```

and so my test of ListBox with CheckBoxes works as I need.

Thank to all you I has learn so much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

XAML:
`DescCompuestaList` is a list of `CheckListGeneric`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DescCompuestaList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding DescCompuesta}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here your `CheckListGeneric` class

```
public class CheckListGeneric: ViewModelBase
{
    #region ..:: Fields ::..

    private bool _isChecked;

    #endregion

    #region ..:: Properties ::..

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string DescCompuesta{ get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can get all selected using a simple query

`var selectedItems = DescCompuestaList.Where(x => x.IsChecked)`

simple as life.

Comment: thnks so much @CelsoLívero I testing you suggestion

Answer (score 1):

How about binding `CheckBox`'s `IsChecked` property to `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property. 
Something like: `IsChecked={Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}`

In your example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lstMaterialesCL}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="lstMaterial" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Name="chkMaterial" Content="{Binding DescCompuesta}" IsChecked={Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: thnks so much @Bubba I testing you suggestion

Comment: If it helps you, don't forget to up-vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's always easiest way to use Blend for making templates.
Open project in blend and make one listBox, then select that ListBox and add template like in picture.
[image]

just to show purpose i have add simple checkBox and TextBlock, and you can make it as u like it.

in ViewModel i have made simple observable collection just to show purpose and bound ItemsSource to Users:

```
public class TestVM 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public TestVM()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
            {
                new User{ IsChecked=true, Name="User1" },
                new User{ IsChecked=false, Name="User2" },
                new User{ IsChecked=true, Name="User3" },
                new User{ IsChecked=false, Name="User3" },
            };
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This way you can make any template you like.